# How to replace ActionBar in 3.0 with AndroidSherlock in 2.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

How to map the code

1.

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

2.

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
.setTabListener(this));
```

3.

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

to something similar in actionBarSherlock

Comment: Why do you want to use ActionBarShelock? You can use the official v7 support library to add an ActionBar to an app which will be compatible with Android v2.1 onwards.

Comment: Use `AppCompat` instead of `ActionBarSherlock`.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

1.xxx extends Activity-->xxx extends SherlockActivity

2.getActionBar()--->getSupportActionBar()

Answer (score 0):

I have  recently replace with sherlock library.

1>please download [zip](http://www.boopathyraja.com/Android_UI_Design.zip) file and follow main activity using this example you can easily replace with sherlock library.